# Replacing/substituting part of a string using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm tidying a string in Python and need to substitute some of the text (following a certain rule) using Regex. In the string (copied below), a place is usually mentioned followed by a comma and then the city's associated mortality rate. The next place is separated with a semi-colon. However there are some examples where the semi-colon is missing and I need to use Regex to add that semi-colon back in (e.g. 'Plymouth, 19 Portsmouth, 15' should be 'Plymouth, 19; Portsmouth, 15').

The text is as follows:

> Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18 ; Bradford, 16 ; Brighton, 14 Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25 ; Derby, 12 ; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21 ; Hull, 19 ; Leeds, 22 ; Leicester, 18 ; London, 17; Manchester,15 ; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18 ; Plymouth, 19 Portsmouth, 15 ; Preston, 23 ; Salford, 14 ; Sheffield, 16 ; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton. 30. The rate in Edinburgh was 14 ;in Glasgow, 23 ; and in Dublin. 22.

I've tried using re.sub() for this using the following formula and using non-capture sets but am doing something very horribly wrong!

```
mystring = [the string here]
re.sub("(?:[0-9])?\s(?:[A-Z0-9]?)", ";", mystring)
```

Is anyone able to help me fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Some parts of the string have space between the number and the semi-colon like `18 ;` do you have to correct those to like `18;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all! In the end, with some experimenting, I have found a different solution:

`re.sub("(?<=\d)[ ;]+", "; ", mystring)`

Effectively, we just look for all cases of one or more spaces and/or semi-colons which are preceded by a number (using a look-back) and then replace the match with `;` .

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
\w,\s*\d+\b(?!\s*;)
```

**Explanation**

- `\w,` Match a word char followed by a comma
- `\s*\d+\b` Match optional whitespace chars followed by 1+ digits and a word boundary
- `(?!\s*;)` Negative lookahead, assert not optional whitespace chars followed by `;` to the right

In the replacement use the full match followed by a semicolon `\g<0>;`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEiTvR/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/f7AOOb).

Example

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\w,\s*\d+\b(?!\s*;)"
s = "Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18 ; Bradford, 16 ; Brighton, 14 Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25 ; Derby, 12 ; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21 ; Hull, 19 ; Leeds, 22 ; Leicester, 18 ; London, 17; Manchester,15 ; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18 ; Plymouth, 19 Portsmouth, 15 ; Preston, 23 ; Salford, 14 ; Sheffield, 16 ; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton. 30. The rate in Edinburgh was 14 ;in Glasgow, 23 ; and in Dublin. 22."
 
 
result = re.sub(pattern, r"\g<0>;", s)
 
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18 ; Bradford, 16 ; Brighton, 14; Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25 ; Derby, 12 ; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21 ; Hull, 19 ; Leeds, 22 ; Leicester, 18 ; London, 17; Manchester,15 ; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18 ; Plymouth, 19; Portsmouth, 15 ; Preston, 23 ; Salford, 14 ; Sheffield, 16 ; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton. 30. The rate in Edinburgh was 14 ;in Glasgow, 23 ; and in Dublin. 22.
```

---

Or without matching newlines and starting the match with a char a-zA-Z

```
[a-zA-Z],[^\S\n]*\d+\b(?![^\S\n]*;)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cobnOs/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a raw string with the following regex `(?<=\w),\s+(?!\w)`, using the `.sub()` function as you were using before to replace the commas with semicolons, here is the code, tell me if you need anymore help, I'll be glad to assist (:

```
import re

mystring = "Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18 ; Bradford, 16 ; Brighton, 14 Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25 ; Derby, 12 ; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21 ; Hull, 19 ; Leeds, 22 ; Leicester, 18 ; London, 17; Manchester,15 ; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18 ; Plymouth, 19 Portsmouth, 15 ; Preston, 23 ; Salford, 14 ; Sheffield, 16 ; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton. 30. The rate in Edinburgh was 14 ;in Glasgow, 23 ; and in Dublin. 22."

newstring = re.sub(r"(?<=\w),\s+(?!\w)", "; ", mystring)

print(newstring)
```

Output should be:

```
Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18; Bradford, 16; Brighton, 14; Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25; Derby, 12; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21; Hull, 19; Leeds, 22; Leicester, 18; London, 17; Manchester, 15; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18; Plymouth, 19; Portsmouth, 15; Preston, 23; Salford, 14; Sheffield, 16; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton. 30. The rate in Edinburgh was 14; in Glasgow, 23; and in Dublin. 22.
```

Answer (score 0):

Plymouth, Wolverhampton, Edinburgh, Glasgow and Dublin all seemed to have issues with the formatting not being as expected.

My assumption is that that you want the city name and the death rate to be extracted from this data. Because of the extra text in some of the cities that makes it difficult.

I would use the numeric values to split the data then use the last word with a capital letter to assume the city. Store these two bits of information in a Python dictionary.

```py
pattern1 = r"(.+?)(\d+)"
pattern2 = r".*([A-Z]\w+)"
all_info = {}
# split to have letter before numbers and numbers
for letters, numbers in re.findall(pattern1, mystring):
    # Find the city name in the letters
    location = re.match(pattern2, letters).group(1)
    # Build a dictionary of the information
    all_info[location] = int(numbers)
```

If you want the specific string you are looking for then you can create that from the Python dictionary.

```py
new_str = '; '.join([f'{key}, {value}' for (key, value) in all_info.items()]) + ';'
```

My full test I used was:

```py
import json
import re

mystring = (
    "Birkenhead, 16; "
    "Birmingham, 15; "
    "Blackburn, 16; "
    "Bolton, 18 ; "
    "Bradford, 16 ; "
    "Brighton, 14 "
    "Bristol, 20; "
    "Cardiff, 25 ;"
    " Derby, 12 ;"
    " Halifax, 20;"
    " Biddersfield, 21 ;"
    " Hull, 19 ;"
    " Leeds, 22 ;"
    " Leicester, 18 ;"
    " London, 17;"
    " Manchester,15 ;"
    " Norwich, 24;"
    " Nottingham, 21;"
    " Oldham, 18 ;"
    " Plymouth, 19"
    " Portsmouth, 15 ;"
    " Preston, 23 ;"
    " Salford, 14 ;"
    " Sheffield, 16 ;"
    " Sunderland, 18;"
    " Wolverhampton. 30."
    " The rate in Edinburgh was 14 ;"
    "in Glasgow, 23 ;"
    " and in Dublin. 22."
)
pattern1 = r"(.+?)(\d+)"
pattern2 = r".*([A-Z]\w+)"
all_info = {}
# split to have letter before numbers and numbers
for letters, numbers in re.findall(pattern1, mystring):
    # Find the city name in the letters
    location = re.match(pattern2, letters).group(1)
    # Build a dictionary of the information
    all_info[location] = int(numbers)
    
print(f"as json data:\n{json.dumps(all_info, indent=4)}")

new_str = '; '.join([f'{key}, {value}' for (key, value) in all_info.items()]) + ';'
print(f"as new string:\n{new_str}")
```

Which gave the following output:

```
as json data:
{
    "Birkenhead": 16,
    "Birmingham": 15,
    "Blackburn": 16,
    "Bolton": 18,
    "Bradford": 16,
    "Brighton": 14,
    "Bristol": 20,
    "Cardiff": 25,
    "Derby": 12,
    "Halifax": 20,
    "Biddersfield": 21,
    "Hull": 19,
    "Leeds": 22,
    "Leicester": 18,
    "London": 17,
    "Manchester": 15,
    "Norwich": 24,
    "Nottingham": 21,
    "Oldham": 18,
    "Plymouth": 19,
    "Portsmouth": 15,
    "Preston": 23,
    "Salford": 14,
    "Sheffield": 16,
    "Sunderland": 18,
    "Wolverhampton": 30,
    "Edinburgh": 14,
    "Glasgow": 23,
    "Dublin": 22
}
as new string:
Birkenhead, 16; Birmingham, 15; Blackburn, 16; Bolton, 18; Bradford, 16; Brighton, 14; Bristol, 20; Cardiff, 25; Derby, 12; Halifax, 20; Biddersfield, 21; Hull, 19; Leeds, 22; Leicester, 18; London, 17; Manchester, 15; Norwich, 24; Nottingham, 21; Oldham, 18; Plymouth, 19; Portsmouth, 15; Preston, 23; Salford, 14; Sheffield, 16; Sunderland, 18; Wolverhampton, 30; Edinburgh, 14; Glasgow, 23; Dublin, 22;
```